# Taking certain string characters and returning the string

Tags: c#, string

I asked this question yesterday but it wasn't well received mainly due to how I asked it so ill try do better this time.

I have a string variable called message. lets say message equals "ABCDABCDABCDABCD"

now I need to do some processing on the characters in the string but not all at the same time, I want to access characters [0][4][8][12] on the first pass of the function, put each of these characters in a string and return it which is easy done if I pass an integer to my function lets say 4 and with in a for loop do

```
if(i % int == 0)
{
   string += message[i];
}
```

this should return "AAAA"

the next time I call the function ill need elements [0][1], [4][5], [8][9], [12][13] and the time after that ill need [0][1][2], [4][5][6], [8][9][10], [12][13][14].

I need the characters returned in a string in the order they were taken, I could do this by changing my int I pass the function but then id need to call the function several times and do work on the returned strings to get them into the order they were taken, which I have already tried and it slowed my program down when dealing with large messages > 10k characters.

Please don't delete or put my question on hold, im quite happy to give more information on my problem if its not clear, ill seldom post to this site and usually try and find a solution myself, there are too many acceptance junkies on here for my liking. but I would appreciate some help from some of them regarding this.Thanks

Edit

I understand its not easy to figure it out and I have to say im not the best at describing it, its a vigenere cracker in WPF, I have done the kasiski examination on a piece of text and graphed out all the data, it finds the key length 90% of the time or gives me the best clue to what the key might be, now im calculating the frequency of bi,tri and quad grams of the message based on the data from the kasiski exam, lets say the key is 5 and the message is "ABCDABCDABCDABCD" im calculating probability on only the characters of the key Im changing so when I try key AAAAA im only wanting to calculate monograms on elements [0][4][9][14] of the message, ill run through 26 characters up to ZAAAA and take the most probable then I move onto element [1] of the key, lets say FAAAA gave the best score on the first element of the key. now I need elements [0][1],[5][6],[9][10][13][14] as im calculating probability on 2 pieces on the key FCAAA, so the length of the key and what key character im working on will determine what elements of the message ill be taking.

Comment: It really helps if you post *actual* code (ideally a short but complete program demonstrating the problem) rather than pseudo-code. Aside from anything else, it makes it easier to post a "corrected" version. It's also not clear how you expect the loop you've got to give (0, 1), (4, 5) etc. Finally, it's really unclear whether you've got working code which is slow, or whether you're still trying to get to code that works at all. (Either way, I'd suggest using StringBuilder...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple program which does what you want, if I understand correctly:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = "ABCDABCDABCDABCD";

        Console.WriteLine(StrangeSubstring(data,4, 1));
        // "AAAA"
        Console.WriteLine(StrangeSubstring(data,4, 2));
        // "ABABABAB"
        Console.WriteLine(StrangeSubstring(data,4, 3));
        // "ABCABCABCABC"
    }

    static string StrangeSubstring(string input, int modulo, int length)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i % modulo == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<length; ++j)
                {
                    if (i+j < input.Length)
                        sb.Append(input[i+j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This solution does what I need, the problem almost seems trivial now, wait until modulus is 0, take all chars upto the required length and append to a string, thanks a lot, I tried a few other solutions posted but they didn't give me the results I needed, this is simple and seems quick enough for smaller texts. will do for now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner with LINQ (I use Batch extension from [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), but you can use your own) which selects all required chars from input string:

```
string message = "ABCDABCDABCDABCD";
int size = 4;
int charsToTake = 2;
var characters = message.Batch(size).SelectMany(b => b.Take(charsToTake));
```

If you need result as string, you can easily create one:

```
var result = new String(characters.ToArray());  
// ABABABAB
```

---

More efficient way - create your own method which will split string by substrings of required length:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToSubstrings(this string s, int length)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index + length < s.Length)
    {
        yield return s.Substring(index, length);
        index += length;
    }

    if (index < s.Length)
        yield return s.Substring(index);
}
```

I would also create method for safe getting substring from start of string (to avoid annoying string length check and passing zero as start index):

```
public static string SubstringFromStart(this string s, int length)
{
    return s.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, length));
}
```

Now its very clear what you are doing:

```
var substrings = message.ToSubstrings(size)
                        .Select(s => s.SubstringFromStart(charsToTake));

var result = String.Concat(substrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your string to a char array :

```
string message="ABCDABCDABCDABCD";
char[] myCharArray = message.ToCharArray();

string result="";
for(int i=0, i<myCharArray.Length -1 ; i++)
{
   if(i%4 ==0)
      result+=myCharArray[i];
}
```

**EDIT 1 :**

```
public string[] myfunction(char[] charArray)
{
   List<string> result = new List<string>();
   for(int i=0, i<charArray.length -1; i=i+4)
   {
      result.add(charArray[i]+charArray[i+1])
   }

   return result.toArray();
}
```

Comment: How does this solve OP's issue? In the code sample the string is already being treated like a character array.

Comment: he can have access to all char in the array and make other function... I will edit my post, wait mnutes please :-D

Comment: Still not seeing the value of a char array.  `for (int i = 0; i < someString.Length; i = i + 4) { result.Add(someString[i] + someString[i + 1]); }` would do the same thing, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be like this

```
         static string MethodName(int range){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for(int i = 0 ; i < str.Length ; i++){
          if(i % 4 == 0){
             sb.Append(str[i]);
             for(int j = i + 1 ; j <= i + range ; j ++){
               if(j >= str.Length)
                     break;             
                  sb.Append(str[j]);
          }
        }
    }
     return sb.ToString();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution. In YourFunction, PatternLength is the length of the character pattern which is repeated (so, 4 for "ABCD"), Offset is where you start in the pattern (e.g. 0 if you start with "A") and SubstringLength is the number of characters.

The function call in Main will give you all "A". If you change SubstringLength to 2, it gives you all "AB". There is no error handling, make sure then PatternLength<=Offest+SubstringLength

```
    namespace Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(YourFunction("ABCABCABCABCABCABCABC", 3, 0,1));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static string YourFunction(string SubString, int PatternLength, int Offset, int SubstringLength)
        {
            string result;
            if (SubString.Length <= PatternLength)
            {
                result = SubString.Substring(Offset, SubstringLength);
            }
            else
            {
                result = YourFunction(SubString.Substring(PatternLength, (SubString.Length - PatternLength)), PatternLength, Offset, SubstringLength) + SubString.Substring(Offset, SubstringLength);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```